# Use triplets of integers vs HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer....>>

Tags: java, hashmap

let's asume that there is a class Pos, implementing Lombok's equals and hashcode and have only immutable 3 integers (int x,y,z)

what may be more effective
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer,T>>> or
HashMap<Pos, T> ?

considering that i register values only at creation, and after that i only read values lots of times from the map, and also very often loop trough that map for every x and z possible for a specific y value (so in first case i even don't need to filter the y value, i just get the map for it, and filter null z maps for that y value)

Comment: Can an answer use dependencies outside Java's main libraries? For instance, there is a triplet class for org.javatuples. What is wrong with the Pos class you currently have?

Comment: you can, but i don't think it will be better than that Pos class, and nothing is wrong with him, just asking what will be faster when using hashmaps, because didn't fully understand that part

Answer (score 1):

## Records

Java 16+ offers a brief class definition now: records. So no need to resort to Lombok for that. See [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

A record is appropriate when the main purpose of your class is to carry data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` and `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record Position ( int x , int y , int z ) {}
```

Collect your `Position` objects.

```
List< Position > positions = new ArrayList<>() ;
positions.add( new Person( 1 , 2 , 3 ) ) ;
…
```

## From stream to map via `Collectors.groupingBy`

Group them by their `y` value.

```
Map< Integer, Set< Position > > positionsByY = 
    positions
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy( Position :: y )
    );
```

When you want all x and z values for a particular valid of `y`, retrieve a list.